# How can the End Point error "405 Method Not Allowed" in WSO2 API Manager be solved?

Tags: api, soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager, endpoint

when I want to add my soap API to WSO2 API Manager and select "I Have a Soap End Point" and I set WSDL URL to "http://10.0.85.53:808/MobileBankingChannel.asmx?wsdl" then I get this error
in End Point field "405 Method Not Allowed"
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are asking to validate the endpoint, the server sends a HEAD method request to the endpoint. I guess your endpoint does not support that. If that is the case, you can simply ignore this and create the API.

Comment: the method is ok in postman how can I check the HEAD?

Comment: Sample HEAD request - curl -I https://reqbin.com/echo -v

Comment: Refer https://reqbin.com/req/c-tmyvmbgu/curl-head-request-example#:~:text=To%20send%20a%20HEAD%20request,still%20respond%20to%20GET%20requests.

Comment: what should I do if The endpoint does not support HEAD method request?

Comment: You can't do anything. I think you can skip doing the validation and create the API

Comment: when I Create A new API and enter new End point the Error appeared again.